# CURL POST/GET URL doesn't work when stored in variable

Tags: php, curl

In a nutshell...

**Doesn't work**

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/test/index.php?id=1&token=723648723";  <-- Set by previous Curl   
$ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
    $html = curl_exec ($ch); 
    echo $html;
```

**Works**

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/test/index.php?id=1&token=723648723"); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
    $html = curl_exec ($ch); 
    echo $html;
```

What gives? I have tried urlencode, urldecode, rawurlencode without success.

Evidently, posting the url in the browser works fine.

**EDIT: I should probably add the url is obtained from another curl running right before this one. If I stored the url in a variable it works, but if I let the other curl set the variable, it doesn't.**

Comment: Did you compare `var_dump($url,'http://www.example.com/test/index.php?id=1&token=723648723');`?

Comment: You might be onto something. They look identical but the string count changes. One is string(123) and the other string(115).

Comment: How about `var_dump(trim($url),'http://www.example.com/test/index.php?id=1&token=723648723');`?

Comment: It returns the same. Weird.

Comment: The string with 123 characters contains "&amp;" while the other "&"

Comment: Thank you everyone who chimed in. I wish I could accept all of your answers. Cheers and have a good day! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/test/index.php?id=1&token=723648723"; // < -- Set by previous Curl
$ch      = curl_init($url); // init with the given $url here

// remove curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);

$html = curl_exec($ch);
if ($html === false) // check for errors
{
    // throw new Exception('Curl error: ' . @curl_error($ch));
    echo 'Curl error: ' . @curl_error($ch);
}

@curl_close($ch); // close properly
echo $html;
```

**UPDATE 3**: clean html, spaces, new lines, replace `&amp;` and force string data type ...

```
$url = (string) trim(strip_tags($url));
$url = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $url);
$ch  = curl_init($url);
// etc
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. Returns "0". It's really weird because when I set the $url variable manually, it works. But if I let my previous curl set $url, it doesn't work. When I echo $url after curl has set it, it displays just fine.

Comment: @bastien `@curl_close($ch); // close properly` close previous curl process too

Comment: @bastien UPDATE: force string data type

Comment: Closing everything properly still returns 0

Comment: Tried force string data. Still no go.. returns 0 =/

Comment: @bastien look closer to the previous results. I'm sure that contains html data. check my UPDATE 2 and go for a beer...